# Overriding java constructor with mozilla rhino

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, rhino

I'm trying to subclass and override the constructors of Packages.org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog in a script using [eclipsescript](http://eclipsescript.org) , however I haven't been able to figure out what to name the constructor methods in the object I pass to JavaAdapter:

```
var searchDialog = new JavaAdapter(Packages.org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog, {
    insert_name_of_first_constructor_here: function(){

    },
    insert_name_of_second_constructor_here: function(){

    },
    open: function(){
       return "hello";
    }
});
```

Is there a special name for constructor functions?